# 'float' object has no attribute 'encode' in Robot framework

Tags: floating-point, encode, robotframework

I want to save a variable value in a file using Create File keyword. Value is a float. When I try to save it using Create File it gives an error

```
'float' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to convert number to string before writing it:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    OperatingSystem


*** Test Cases ***
Write
    ${str}=        Set Variable         3.1415926
    ${flt}=        Convert To Number    ${str}
    ${str2}=       Convert To String    ${flt}
    Create File    demo.txt             ${str2}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can save after converting it to string.

Comment: @pekka you read my mind :)  noticed your answer just a second before posting mine! your example looks much better than mine though ;)